# CSRF token using SPA

Tags: laravel, vue.js, csrf

I'm using Vue js for the SPA and Laravel for the backend. It all works fine but once a form has been submitted the crsf token obviously hasn't refreshed so when I go to then submit another form I get a `TokenMismatchException`.

I can't put the csrf token into the form as vue throws an error when it attempts to render as the form is a component within vue.

I can access the csrf token using vue's default common headers by searching for `name=_token` which will work on the first request but on any requests after Laravel will return a `TokenMismatchException` as the token has been used recently by the currently logged in user.

I need to figure out a way so that the token can be refreshed without having to refresh the page as then it wouldn't be an SPA.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Nope, that just says how to access the csrf token. I can do that as I explained. The problem is that once I have logged in for example, I cannot use the same csrf token again it needs to be refreshed but seeing as the page doesn't refresh the token cannot refresh. @manniL

Comment: you can 1) https://laravel-news.com/excluding-routes-from-the-csrf-middleware 2)generate a new token everytime over xhr

Comment: Which middleware are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Something funky is going on within your setup, possibly some configuration with Vue, as your second statement is a bit off:

> I can access the csrf token using vue's default common headers by
>   searching for name=_token which will work on the first request but on
>   any requests after Laravel will return a TokenMismatchException as the
>   token has been used recently by the currently logged in user.

The above just isn't the case, unless they have logged out and logged back in, otherwise you can continue to use the same token.

I'm building a couple of SPA's with Laravel as the backend at the moment, the only time I do an actual traditional form submission is during a log in or log out sequence (so a full page refresh). The rest of the time it's just the same page using the same token.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local variable with the csrf token value and assign it to the window like so (In your main layout blade file):

```
<script>
window.AppSettings = {
    csrfToken: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
}
</script>
```

then in your axios/vue-resource request use it:

```
axios.post("/some/path", { my: data, _token: AppSettings.csrfToken })
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
  })
```

The other workaround (not recommended at all) is to disable it in your middleware

in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
protected $except = [
    "your/path/to/ignore"
];
```

But I'll go with the first option.