# SPA Vue on Laravel post method not allowed. Setting csrf token?

Tags: vue.js, axios, laravel-8

I know this question is everywhere. But most of them are using blade and the rest of them have not being useful. I have tried in many ways to set this csrf-token but is not working.
I'm trying to make an SPA with laravel API and the vuejs included in laravel 8. No matter what I keep getting "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

This is my route on the route.api file is:

```
Route::post('api/authenticate', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate']);
```

I'm including a UsersService.js file where I'm planning to define all the api calls in functions in order to call them from the necessary components. So I have here the axios call.

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  authenticate (formData) {
    return axios.post('api/authenticate', { formData })
  }
}
```

The only thing I have clear is that I need the token and in order to be sure that is there I have added a script on the layout blade file where I load my components like this. So I can access the token with AppSettings.csrfToken

```
<script>
  window.AppSettings = {
    csrfToken: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
  }
</script>
```

And this is my component

```
<template>
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="form-signin" style="width: 100%; max-width: 330px; padding: 15px; margin: 0 auto;">
                <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="" v-model="formData.email">
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" v-model="formData.password">
                <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" @click="login">Sign in</button>
                <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">© 2017-2018</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import UsersService from '../../services/UsersService.js'
    export default {
        data(){
          return{
                formData: {
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    deviceName: 'browser',
                    _token: AppSettings.csrfToken
                }
            }
        },
        async created () {
        },
       methods:{
           async login(){
                const res = await UsersService.authenticate(this.formData)
                console.log(res)
           },
        }
    }
</script>
```

cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
    ],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

I have the token, right there, I can read it, what should I do with it, in which way must be set on the axios in order to allow this POST request.

Following the sanctum guid in laravel's website I have also added axios.defaults.withCredentials = true; but it does nothing.
Also like this answer [CSRF token using SPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41817303/csrf-token-using-spa)

return axios.post('api/authenticate', { formData, _token: AppSettings.csrfToken })

But that also didn't work, for sure I'm not understanding something or I'm looking in the wrong place. I've ran out of ideas, any help here?

Comment: Well. I checked another request instead of my custom http://localhost/api/authenticate or any other the one that works is http://localhost/login. Why?

Comment: Well. I checked another request instead of my custom http://localhost/api/authenticate or any other the one that works is http://localhost/login. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably got sidetracked bcs CSRF is a common problem, but the error does not mention CSRF, and the problem has nothing to do with CSRF.  The error tells you there is something wrong with your routing.

[From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files):

> Routes defined in the `routes/api.php` file are nested within a route group by the `RouteServiceProvider`. Within this group, the `/api` URI prefix is automatically applied so you do not need to manually apply it to every route in the file.

The route you have in `routes/api.php` is:

```
Route::post('api/authenticate', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate']);
```

So because that is automatically prefixed with `/api`, it actually defines the route `/api/api/authenticate`.  Your Axios code POSTs to `/api/authenticate`, but that has no associated route.